# Cannot append d3 svg element to backbone element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, svg, d3.js

So I'm doing this in my init function in my view -

```
    var svg = d3.select(".timechart-container").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

The reason I do it to timechart-container is because I'm relying on the view to create its own el.

```
app.TimeChartView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'timechart-container',
```

This is the parent view's render function-

```
render: function(){
    this.$el.append(this.rightView.render().$el);
    this.$el.append(this.centerView.$el);
    this.centerView.render();
    return this;
}
```

When I do d3.select("body")...

the svg element appends.

With my current code nothing is appended to the div with that class.

Why?

Comment: I don't know about the `backbone` but can you say me this whether you run the `d3` code after creating the div or before creating the div using `backbone`?

Comment: Where did you call the `d3.select(".timechart-container")` ?